# Do disguises that cover your head or face make you less likely or be less quickly detected? Any effects caused by a head or face-covering disguise?

Tags: hitman-absolution

I asked this question, because I remember (might be wrong though) that in Hitman: Blood Money, NPCs could be on the lookout for a "bald man", depending on certain player actions reported by a witness. An alert message will pop-up saying something to that effect. This makes the bald Agent 47 more likely to be detected by the now more alerted guards/hostiles if he's wearing clothes that expose his head, even if disguised. I'm wondering if Hitman: Absolution has a similar game mechanic, or if head-covering disguise just has any effect on enemy detection of 47.

I'm also wondering if face-covering disguises can make 47 be less likely or be less quickly detected. Even with the same type of disguises, one could have a head or face-covering version, while another one could have 47's head fully exposed.

**Do disguises that cover your head or face make you less likely or be less quickly detected? Any effects caused by a head or face-covering disguise?**

Comment: Are you sure about this? No matter what costume with a hat or without it was always the same detection I think?

Comment: @Lyrion Are you talking about Absolution, or previous Hitman games? If it's about Absolution, I am not sure, hence the question. =) In Hitman: Blood Money, I remember that head-covering disguises will help lessen likelihood of detection if enemies are looking for a "bald man" (an in-game notice will pop-up if they are looking).

Comment: I also disagree, I think that the "bald man"  just flavor text. To the best of my knowledge there was only one detection threshold in the previous games. I don't know about absolution.

Comment: @SteveV. In Hitman: Blood Money, if a witness sees you commit a heinous act, they could report this, and then a message saying something like "the guards are now looking for a bald man" will pop-up. If your head is covered, you are not more likely to be detected by the now more alerted guards (which makes sense, because no one will know that you're bald). Anyway, even if it does not happen in previous Hitman games, my question still stands.

Comment: Right, the current question still stands.

Comment: The detection rate is the same for anyone in the same outfit as you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, Agent 47 loses the face coverings, so you end up with a bald guy wearing safety goggles, and thus he's still spotted by members of the same class of disguise (maintenance worker/plumber/policeman etc).

> There is at least one noticable exception I've noticed, later in the game when you are assassinating Dexter's lady-friend, there are two or three bodyguards wearing full balaclavas. If you disguise as one of these guys, you can walk around almost the entire house without being spotted, as 47 puts on the balaclava. But this is mostly to do with the fact that you're a different "class" to most of the guards in the house, as other guards who are wearing the full-face masks are somehow miraculously able to tell that you're not one of them, even though you're not showing any skin.

Comment: What about head-covering disguises that hide 47's baldness (not necessarily his face)? (as compared to disguise of the same type that is not head-covering)

Comment: @galacticninja - No difference amongst users of the same class as '47. So the dumbass texan bodyguards might not notice you, but other maintenance workers will.